# Wired ethernet not working on Dell Latitude e5450 (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: networking, drivers, dell, ethernet

Long time lurker, first time poster. I know a lot of others have had somewhat similar questions and I've reviewed them all and haven't been able to fix my issue.
Please excuse my question format if its incorrect.

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 20.04 on a Dell Latitude e5450. Wifi is working fine, but wired ethernet is not working. I'm still a Linux amateur, but I feel like this is a driver issue?

[lshw -C network](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eiqle.png)

```
sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Ethernet Connection I218-LM
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 19
       bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
       version: 03
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7200000-f721ffff memory:f7243000-f7243fff ioport:f080(size=32)
  *-network
       description: Wireless interface
       product: QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
       vendor: Qualcomm Atheros
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlp2s0
       version: 01
       serial: b0:c0:90:08:d5:cb
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=ath9k driverversion=5.8.0-45-generic firmware=N/A ip=192.168.1.181 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
       resources: irq:19 memory:f7000000-f707ffff memory:f7080000-f708ffff
```

```
sudo lspci -kv
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I218-LM (rev 03)
        DeviceName:  Onboard LAN
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I218-LM
        Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 20
        Memory at f7200000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=128K]
        Memory at f7243000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=4K]
        I/O ports at f080 [size=32]
        Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 2
        Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
        Capabilities: [e0] PCI Advanced Features
        Kernel modules: e1000e
```

[lspci -k | grep -i net](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t2gDf.png)

```
lspci -k | grep -i net
00:19.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I218-LM (rev 03)
        Subsystem: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection I218-LM
02:00.0 Network controller: Qualcomm Atheros QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter (rev 01)
        Subsystem: Dell QCA9565 / AR9565 Wireless Network Adapter
```

I think this means that the hardware is recognized by the OS, but there is no driver that tells it how to work?
I attempted to install the intel driver from [here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005480/network-and-i-o/ethernet-products.html) but I'm pretty unfamiliar with this process and when I ran into issues I don't really know how to troubleshoot them.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Additional screenshots for context:

[uname -r](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R6DYz.png)

```
uname -r
5.8.0-45-generic
```

[ifconfig -a](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yytRh.png)

```
ifconfig -a
lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 389  bytes 37485 (37.4 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 389  bytes 37485 (37.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

wlp2s0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.1.181  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.1.255
        inet6 fe80::c1f2:d872:2156:e6c5  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether b0:c0:90:08:d5:cb  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 21903  bytes 10778568 (10.7 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 2500  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6002  bytes 810128 (810.1 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

[ip addr](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jzf89.png)

```
ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether b0:c0:90:08:d5:cb brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 192.168.1.181/24 brd 192.168.1.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute wlp2s0
       valid_lft 81437sec preferred_lft 81437sec
    inet6 fe80::c1f2:d872:2156:e6c5/64 scope link noprefixroute
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

[cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iLJgX.png)

```
cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
# Let NetworkManager manage all devices on this system
network:
  version: 2
```

Thank you!!!

EDIT1: Pasted text directly to question instead of just screenshots.

EDIT2: Added sudo lspci -kv. Lots of help [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/linuxquestions/comments/m8gc1g/ubuntu_2004_install_wired_ethernet_not_working/). Thanks!

Comment: Please include all text as part of the question not add on pictures.

Comment: Ok, added the text directly. Thanks!

Comment: an alternative is a USB ethernet adapter, and I would recommend tying it to eth0     https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/386162/how-to-set-up-an-usb-ethernet-interface-in-linux

Comment: Yeah, I considered that.... At this point, its just principle for me. I appreciate it!

Comment: Hello, did you succeed to the issue ? I'm in the same situation...